# How to set the parameters of SVM with polynomial kernel?

Tags: svm

I learned there two parameters of the polynomial kernel: the intercept and the degree of the polynomial.

The question is, how do we decide the values of these parameters?

From where I should start to decide the value?

Answer (score 1):

The degree of polynomial kernel is a hyper-parameter and you set it from the beginning, before performing any training/test. You typically choose it via cross-validation. But, the intercept is a parameter (not a hyper-parameter) of the model together with coefficients corresponding to features and is found via optimization.

Comment: How do I set that? Based on what?

Comment: Degree is a hyper-parameter, in its simplest form, you can just iterate over a couple of options and choose the one with the highest cross-validation performance, for example.